# Does f(x) = g(u)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x) = x + \sqrt{2-x}$ and $g(u) = u + \sqrt{2-u}$ is it true that $f = g$?

I squared both sides $\sqrt{x + \sqrt {2-x}} = \sqrt{u + \sqrt {2-u}}$

$\sqrt{x} + 2-x = \sqrt{u} + 2-u$

I then subtracted $-2$ and added to the left side of the equation.

$\sqrt{x} -x = \sqrt{u} -u$

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: what the hell are you doing ? of course $f=g$ !!

Comment: Ok, dumb question, why?

Comment: The symbols $u,x$ are only place holders in the above expressions.

Comment: Also why didn't my MathJax set up work?

Comment: Note that it is true that $f=g$ but it is **not**  true that $f(x)=g(u)$ (unless $x,u$ have some appropriate relationship).

Comment: $x$ and $u$ are variables.

Comment: Thanks copper.hat. So the variables essentially are void of any meaning until they have an assigned element?

Comment: Well, their meaning is dependent on context. When we write $f(x) = \text{something}$, if $x$ appears in the something, then it refers to the symbol on the left hand side. These issues arise because we use different names to refer to same things (the symbols $f,g$ refer to the same function) and the same names to refer to different things (no clear example here).

Answer (score 3):

Even though the RHS are similar(just replace u by x)enter preformatted text here, it still depend on the domain and co-domain of the functions

If two function have the`same domain and co-domain`,also `f(x)=g(x) for any x inside the domain`, f=g.

Answer (score 1):

We can't answer your question since it depends on the domain of $f$ and $g$. For example if we assume that the domain of $f$ is $[2,+\infty)$ and the domain of $g$ is $[3,+\infty)$ then $f\ne g$.

Comment: it's not the question and even if it were, yours would be a comment, not an answer !

Comment: It's not you who decides if I put it in the comments or in answer and I hope you do not down-vote because you put a fake comment and you insist on your error.

Comment: @idm: This certainly is a relevant feature of the question, unless you are insisting that the answer is definitively *no* because $x\neq u$. (But in the post the OP asks $f=g$ specifically.)

Answer (score 1):

While $f=g$, it is in general *not* true that $f(x)=g(u)$.

Notice that $f(x)=x+\sqrt{2-x}$. Notice also that $g(x)=x+\sqrt{2-x}$ $\dagger$. Thus, $f(x)=g(x)$, and $f=g$.

$\dagger$ Why does $g(x)=x+\sqrt{2-x}$?

Well, we know that $g(u)=u+\sqrt{2-u}$, **for all $\boldsymbol u$**. Thus, if we left $u=x$, we get $g(x)=x+\sqrt{2-x}$.